# AngularJS Post data as key-value pair to a asp.net page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

I am trying to post key-value pair data from angular application to a asp.net page however I am not able to receive the result at the asp.net page.

**Example Data**

```
 {fullName: "Vikas Bansal", userId: "1001387693259813", userimageurl: "http://graph.facebook.com/1001387693259813/picture?width=250&height=250"}
```

**Angular Code**

```
    var postData = {
        fullName: $scope.name,
        userId: $scope.userId,
        userimageurl: $scope.userImage
    };

    var postUrl = 'http://localhost:41115/Index.aspx';

    $http({
        url: postUrl,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        data: postData
    }).then(function (responce) {
        console.log(responce);
    }, function (responce) {
        console.log(responce);
    });
```

**Asp.net Page Code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var userId = Request.Form["userId"];    /// getting null
    var fullName = Request.Form["fullName"];    /// getting null
    var img = Request.Form["userimageurl"]; /// getting null
}
```

In asp.net page all variables are null.

[image]

**EDIT**

By changing content type to `'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` in angularJs post request

and by using `var strJSON = (new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd());` I am able get the posted json

but I am still wondering if there is a way to get key-value pairs directly?

like this `var userId = Request.Form["userId"];`

Comment: You have content type mismatch.  Your payload is JSON but you told ASP that it's Form.  Set your `Content-Type` to `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: @KKKKKKKK used this but did not receive any value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your payload is actually `JSON` but you tried to pass as a `FormData` object.

You'll need to make a `FormData()` object.  Then

(1) Tell AngularJs not to serialize it by using the `angular.identity` function.

(2)  Angular's default header for **PUT** and **POST** requests is `application/json`, so you'll want to override that too.  The browser sets the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` and fills in the correct boundary.

Try this:

```
var postData = new FormData();
postData.append("fullName", $scope.name);
postData.append("userId", $scope.userId);
postData.append("userimageurl", $scope.userImage);

$http.post(postUrl, postData, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
}).then(function(data) {
    //success
}, function(error) {
    //error
});
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. I request you to please provide some details on `transformRequest: angular.identity,` and why did you set `'Content-Type': undefined `. Many many thanks